# Extracting an Array of Structs in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have an external table in hive

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE FOO (  
  TS string,  
  customerId string,  
  products array< struct <productCategory:string, productId:string> >  
)  
PARTITIONED BY (ds string)  
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'some.serde'  
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('error.ignore'='true')  
LOCATION 'some_locations'  
;
```

A record of the table may hold data such as:

```
1340321132000, 'some_company', [{"productCategory":"footwear","productId":"nik3756"},{"productCategory":"eyewear","productId":"oak2449"}]
```

Do anyone know if there is a way to simply extract all the productCategory from this record and return it as an array of productCategories without using explode.  Something like the following:

```
["footwear", "eyewear"]
```

Or do I need to write my own GenericUDF, if so, I do not know much Java (a Ruby person), can someone give me some hints?  I read some instructions on UDF from Apache Hive.  However, I do not know which collection type is best to handle array, and what collection type to handle structs?

===

I have somewhat answered this question by writing a GenericUDF, but I ran into 2 other problems.  It is in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694555/a-genericudf-function-to-extract-a-field-from-an-array-of-structs)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use either the `inline` or `explode` functions, like so:

```
SELECT 
    TS,
    customerId,
    pCat,
    pId,
FROM FOO 
LATERAL VIEW inline(products) p AS pCat, pId
```

Otherwise you can write UDF.  Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716165/how-to-query-struct-array-with-hive-get-json-object) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694555/a-genericudf-function-to-extract-a-field-from-an-array-of-structs) for that. Along with the following resources:

- [Matthew Rathbone's guide to writing generic UDFs](http://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2013/08/10/guide-to-writing-hive-udfs.html)
- [Mark Grover's how to guide](http://mark.thegrovers.ca/tech-blog/how-to-write-a-hive-udf)
- [the baynote blog post on generic UDFs](http://www.baynote.com/2012/11/a-word-from-the-engineers/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use json serde or build-in functions get_json_object, json_tuple.

With [rcongiu's Hive-JSON SerDe](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde) the usage will be:

define table:

```
CREATE TABLE complex_json (
DocId string,
Orders array<struct<ItemId:int, OrderDate:string>>)
```

load sample json into it (it is important for this data to be one-lined):

```
{"DocId":"ABC","Orders":[{"ItemId":1111,"OrderDate":"11/11/2012"},{"ItemId":2222,"OrderDate":"12/12/2012"}]}
```

Then fetching orders ids is as easy as:

```
SELECT Orders.ItemId FROM complex_json LIMIT 100;
```

It will return the list of ids for you:

> itemid 
>   [1111,2222]

Proven to return correct results on my environment. Full listing:

```
add jar hdfs:///tmp/json-serde-1.3.6.jar;

CREATE TABLE complex_json (
  DocId string,
  Orders array<struct<ItemId:int, OrderDate:string>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe';

LOAD DATA INPATH '/tmp/test.json' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE complex_json;

SELECT Orders.ItemId FROM complex_json LIMIT 100;
```

Read more here:

http://thornydev.blogspot.com/2013/07/querying-json-records-via-hive.html

Answer (score 0):

If size of array is fixed ( like 2 ). Please try:

```
products[0].productCategory,products[1].productCategory
```

But if not, UDF should be the right solution. I guess that you could do it in JRuby. GL!

Comment: Thanks, but the size of the array is not fixed.  While good idea to use JRuby, for this, need to use Java to write the GenericUDF.  Worse is, there is not much reference in writing GenericUDF.