# A GenericUDF Function to Extract a Field From an Array of Structs‏

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions, udf

I am trying to write a GenericUDF function to collect all of a specific struct field(s) within an array for each record, and return them in an array as well.

I wrote the GenericUDF (as below), and it seems to work but:

1) It does not work when I am performing this on an external table, it works fine on a managed table, any idea?

2) I am having a tough time writing a test on this.  I have attached the test I have so far, and it does not work, 
always getting 'java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspector' or cannot cast String to LazyString', 
my question is how do I supply a list of structs for the evalue method?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE FOO (  
  TS string,  
  customerId string,  
  products array< struct<productCategory:string> >  
)  
PARTITIONED BY (ds string)  
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'some.serde'  
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('error.ignore'='true')  
LOCATION 'some_locations'  
;
```

A row of record holds:
    `1340321132000, 'some_company', [{"productCategory":"footwear"},{"productCategory":"eyewear"}]`

This is my code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Description;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentLengthException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentTypeException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazyString;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ListObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspector.Category;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.PrimitiveObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StructField;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StructObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.StringObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@Description(name = "extract_product_category",
    value = "_FUNC_( array< struct<productcategory:string> > ) - Collect all product category field values inside an array of struct(s), and return the results in an array<string>",
    extended = "Example:\n SELECT _FUNC_(array_of_structs_with_product_category_field)")
public class GenericUDFExtractProductCategory
        extends GenericUDF
{
    private ArrayList ret;

    private ListObjectInspector listOI;
    private StructObjectInspector structOI;
    private ObjectInspector prodCatOI;

    @Override
    public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] args)
            throws UDFArgumentException
    {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            throw new UDFArgumentLengthException("The function extract_product_category() requires exactly one argument.");
        }

        if (args[0].getCategory() != Category.LIST) {
            throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(0, "Type array<struct> is expected to be the argument for extract_product_category but " + args[0].getTypeName() + " is found instead");
        }

        listOI = ((ListObjectInspector) args[0]);
        structOI = ((StructObjectInspector) listOI.getListElementObjectInspector());

        if (structOI.getAllStructFieldRefs().size() != 1) {
            throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(0, "Incorrect number of fields in the struct, should be one");
        }

        StructField productCategoryField = structOI.getStructFieldRef("productCategory");
        //If not, throw exception
        if (productCategoryField == null) {
            throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(0, "NO \"productCategory\" field in input structure");
        }

        //Are they of the correct types?
        //We store these object inspectors for use in the evaluate() method
        prodCatOI = productCategoryField.getFieldObjectInspector();

        //First are they primitives
        if (prodCatOI.getCategory() != Category.PRIMITIVE) {
            throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(0, "productCategory field must be of string type");
        }

        //Are they of the correct primitives?
        if (((PrimitiveObjectInspector)prodCatOI).getPrimitiveCategory() != PrimitiveObjectInspector.PrimitiveCategory.STRING) {
            throw new UDFArgumentTypeException(0, "productCategory field must be of string type");
        }

        ret = new ArrayList();

        return ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardListObjectInspector(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector);
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList evaluate(DeferredObject[] arguments)
            throws HiveException
    {
        ret.clear();

        if (arguments.length != 1) {
            return null;
        }

        if (arguments[0].get() == null) {
        return null;
        }

        int numElements = listOI.getListLength(arguments[0].get());

        for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
            LazyString prodCatDataObject = (LazyString) (structOI.getStructFieldData(listOI.getListElement(arguments[0].get(), i), structOI.getStructFieldRef("productCategory")));
            Text productCategoryValue = ((StringObjectInspector) prodCatOI).getPrimitiveWritableObject(prodCatDataObject);
            ret.add(productCategoryValue);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayString(String[] strings)
    {
        assert (strings.length > 0);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("extract_product_category(");
        sb.append(strings[0]);
        sb.append(")");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

My Test:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDF.DeferredObject;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ListObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StructObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestGenericUDFExtractShas
{
    ArrayList<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<ObjectInspector> fieldObjectInspectors = new ArrayList<ObjectInspector>();

    @Test
    public void simpleTest()
        throws Exception
    {
        ListObjectInspector firstInspector = new MyListObjectInspector();

        ArrayList test = new ArrayList();
        test.add("test");

        ArrayList test2 = new ArrayList();
        test2.add(test);

        StructObjectInspector soi = ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardStructObjectInspector(test, test2);

        fieldNames.add("productCategory");
           fieldObjectInspectors.add(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector);

        GenericUDF.DeferredObject firstDeferredObject = new MyDeferredObject(test2);

        GenericUDF extract_product_category = new GenericUDFExtractProductCategory();

        extract_product_category.initialize(new ObjectInspector[]{firstInspector});

        extract_product_category.evaluate(new DeferredObject[]{firstDeferredObject});
    }

    public class MyDeferredObject implements DeferredObject
    {
        private Object value;

        public MyDeferredObject(Object value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public Object get() throws HiveException
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    private class MyListObjectInspector implements ListObjectInspector
    {
        @Override
        public ObjectInspector getListElementObjectInspector()
        {
            return ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardStructObjectInspector(fieldNames, fieldObjectInspectors);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getListElement(Object data, int index)
        {
            List myList = (List) data;
            if (myList == null || index > myList.size()) {
                return null;
            }
            return myList.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public int getListLength(Object data)
        {
            if (data == null) {
                return -1;
            }
            return ((List) data).size();
        }

        @Override
        public List<?> getList(Object data)
        {
            return (List) data;
        }

        @Override
        public String getTypeName()
        {
            return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public Category getCategory()
        {
            return Category.LIST;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the testing, but with a caveat discussed below, I think I have a solution for the issue with external tables.

In adapting your code to my needs I changed string to long in the evaluate method:

your code:

```
LazyString prodCatDataObject = (LazyString) (structOI.getStructFieldData(listOI.getListElement(arguments[0].get(), i), structOI.getStructFieldRef("productCategory")));
Text productCategoryValue = ((StringObjectInspector) prodCatOI).getPrimitiveWritableObject(prodCatDataObject);
```

my old code:

```
LazyLong indDataObject = (LazyLong) (structOI.getStructFieldData(listOI.getListElement(arguments[0].get(), i), structOI.getStructFieldRef(indexName)));
LongWritable indValue = ((LazyLongObjectInspector) indOI).getPrimitiveWritableObject(indDataObject);
```

You can see they are the same logic with different data types etc.

This worked for me with non-external table.  Did not work with external table.

I was able to resolve this by replacing my old code with this:

```
long indValue = (Long) (structOI.getStructFieldData(listOI.getListElement(arguments[0].get(), i), structOI.getStructFieldRef(indexName)));
```

In another version, where I was returning text

You can probably do something similar, namely by casting to text / string in the first step.

You may also have to change `public Text evaluate(DeferredObject[] arguments)` to `public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] arguments)`.

Source code for some working UDFs that handle array is available [here](https://github.com/chorbl/HiveUDFs/tree/master/src/main/java).

Now for the caveat:  this does not appear to work with tables stored as ORC.  (neither does the original code, mind you).  I will probably create a question about this.  I am not sure what the issue is.